# unhandled error on npm-start with create react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I first installed npm after starting npm is the problem

my operating system: Windows 7 64bit

I try in phpstorm and vscode
my xampp is free port 80 , 443 but my project is a problem when npm start?

my Error::

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\untitled1>npm start

> untitled1@0.1.0 start C:\xampp\htdocs\untitled1
> react-scripts start

Starting the development server...

**events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^**

Error: **spawn cmd ENOENT**
←[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)←[39m
←[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)←[39m
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)←[39m
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
←[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)←[39m
←[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)←[39m
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)←[39m {
  errno: ←[32m'ENOENT'←[39m,
  code: ←[32m'ENOENT'←[39m,
  syscall: ←[32m'spawn cmd'←[39m,
  path: ←[32m'cmd'←[39m,
  spawnargs: [ ←[32m'/s'←[39m, ←[32m'/c'←[39m, ←[32m'start'←[39m, ←[32m'""'←[39m, ←[32m'/b'←[39m, ←[32m'"http://localhost:3000/"'←[39m ]
}

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! untitled1@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the untitled1@0.1.0 start script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Amir Mousavi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-21T07_29_37_935Z-debug.log

enter code here
```

Comment: Refer this: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7061

Answer (score 1):

first step :

> in root project open package.json

two-step :

> change this version : "react-scripts": "^2.1.8"